# How to send multiple products details for sale internetsecure API

Tags: c#, .net, api

I got from internetsecure help library that must be followed with the transaction details to be submitted for processing. An example of a simple XML Transaction request as given below:

```
<FORM name=isecure action=https://secure.internetsecure.com/process.cgi method=post> 
<INPUT type=hidden value=X name=xxxRequestMode> 
<TEXTAREA name=xxxRequestData rows=37 cols=99> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <TranxRequest>
<GatewayID>00004</GatewayID> 
<Products>1.01::1::001::Test Product 1::{TEST}</Products> 
<xxxName>John Smith</xxxName> 
....
....
....
</TEXTAREA> 
<BR> 
<INPUT type=submit value="SUBMIT PAYMENT"> 
</FORM >
```

Problem is here I am not able to send more then one products for sale

```
<Products>1.01::1::001::Test Product 1::{TEST}</Products>
```

Help library : https://www.internetsecure.com/Elavon/ShowPage.asp?page=XML5&q=2

Comment: Can you place your sample of XML you are using to send multiple products in transaction?

Comment: '<Products>
<product>1.01::1::001::Test Product 1::{TEST}<product>
<product>9.99::1::002::Test Product 2::{TEST}<product>
</Products>'

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this ***1.01::1::001::Test Product 1::{TEST}|2.00::1::002::Test Product 2::{TEST}*** 
you separate each product with a pipe | I found this information on there help pages below is the link.
https://www.internetsecure.com/Elavon/ShowPage.asp?page=APSM&q=1

they show an example with basic HTML for Merchant Link, but the products are passed the same way for there Merchant DIRECT Method XML.